# Getline() and cin manipulate dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation, cin, getline

I'm totally lost and confused and could use some help.
I'm currently working on a small command line-based game. For this I wrote a class *Inventory*, dynamically creating an array of *invSpace*-objects, each space representing a pair of a pointer to an *Item* (another class of mine) and a integer, depicting a quantity. Here's the code:

```
class invSpace {
public:
    Item *item;
    int quantity;
    invSpace() {
        item = NULL;
        quantity = 0;
    }
};

class Inventory {
private:
    invSpace* spaces = NULL;
    size_t size;

public:
int free_space() {
    int free = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (spaces[i].item == NULL) {
                free++;
            }
        }
        return free;
    }

    Inventory() {}
    Inventory(size_t new_size) {                        
        size = new_size;
        spaces = new invSpace[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //I know this is obsolete because
            spaces[i].item = NULL;       //of the invSpace constructor, I
            spaces[i].quantity = 0;      //just did this for testing
        }

    ~Inventory() {
        delete[] spaces;
    }

    invSpace& operator[](int index) {
        return spaces[index];
    }
};
```

There are some more methods in this class, like for adding, deleting and searching for items, but those don't matter now. So this is basically just a simple array within one object, dynamically allocating memory in the constructor and with some extra methods. After being created, the array contains zero elements, or Items, so the `free_space()` method should return the size of the array. But it doesn't. It returns about half of the size.

My first thought was that something went wrong with the allocation. But at a second glance I noticed that the Inventory is totally fine directly after being created; with exactly as many spaces as requested, all of them set to item=NULL/quantity=0. But after a call of `getline()` at the start of `main()` that scans user input and saves it to a string for further analyzing, some spaces get filled with random addresses and integers.

Even stranger, with each new call of `getline()` some spaces are freed, some others filled. As far as my debugging, experimenting and testing goes, none of these addresses belong to any variable in my program, they are just plain random. Also, at no point is there be any interference with the Inventory and the `getline()` function or the string it returns. In fact, after being created, no part of this object is used anywhere in the code beside the `free_space()` method. What's even stranger is that *spaces* in the *Inventory* class is marked private, so a method is required to meddle with this pointer/array (or so I would expect).

This problem occurs with `getline()` and `cin` but not with any of C's `<stdio.h>` input stream functions. Using `malloc()` instead of `new[]` makes no difference. Of course, I could use something like `scanf()` for the reading from the console. Still, I just want to know why all these things happen. I have absolutely no idea.

Thanks in advance for every answer!

EDIT:
I narrowed the whole code so that it still produces the same error, also changed `free_space()` so that it prints adress and integer if present:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Item {
public:
    static map<string, Item*> itemlist;
    string name;
    string description;

    Item() {}
    Item(const string new_name, const string new_description) {
        name = new_name;
        description = new_description;
        itemlist.insert(pair<string, Item*> (name, this));      
    }
};

map<string, Item*> Item::itemlist;

/*The more Items are declared, the more random adresses appear in the
inventory*/
Item item01("sword", "A sharp and deadly weapon.");
Item item02("shield", "This will protect you. To a certain extent.");
Item item03("stick", "What is this for exactly?");
Item item04("bottle of water", "A bottle full of refreshing spring water.");

class invSpace {                    
public:
    Item *item;
    int quantity;

    invSpace() {
        item = NULL;
        quantity = 0;
    }
 };

class Inventory {
private:
    invSpace* spaces = NULL;
    size_t size;

public:
    int free_space() {
        int free = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (spaces[i].item == NULL) {
                free++;
                cout << i << " = free" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << spaces[i].item << " / " << spaces[i].quantity << endl;
            }
        }
        return free;
    }

    Inventory() {}
    Inventory(size_t new_size) {    
        size = new_size;
        spaces = new invSpace[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            spaces[i].item = NULL;
            spaces[i].quantity = 0;

        }
    }

    ~Inventory() {
        delete[] spaces;
    }

};

class Player {
public:
    string name;
    Inventory inventory;

    Player(const string new_name) {
        inventory = Inventory(40);
        name = new_name;
    }
 };

Player player("Me");

int main() {
string input;
//Inventory inventory(40); //no error when declared outside the Player class

while (1) {
    cout << "\n>> ";
    getline(cin, input);
    if (input == "x") {
        break;      
    }
    else {
        player.inventory.free_space();
    }
}
}
```

Some things I noticed: No error occurs if the inventory isn't part of a Player-object. If it is but no Items are declared only the first inventory space receives a random adress (and int value) after the first call of `getline()`.
The more Items there are, the more random adresses I get, it seems...

Comment: and the getline() code is ...?

Comment: What's the reason why you're not using `std::vector`?  All of this is implemented in the `vector` class.

Comment: With strings do you mean `std::string` or `char[]` (maybe improperly allocated)?

Comment: It seems you have a memory corruption. If you want us to diagnose it, we need to see code that reproduces the error. Try narrowing it down as much as possible before you post (see [MCVE]). Also try debugging your code by running it through *Valgrind* or use one of the sanitizers.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I added the narrowed code to my first post above as well as some things I noticed while shortening it. I'm curious if it produces the same error when you compile it... In regard to your comments: I'm aware of `vector`, just wanted to try something like that on my own. And I'm using `std::string`.